# Not able to access Ubuntu remote machine via X2Go client?

Tags: 18.04, x2go, x2goclient

I installed X2Go in my remote machine and when i am trying to access this machine via X2Go Client from Windows10 machine i am getting a black screen which exited within a few second after login .The message its showing something like this.

```
NXPROXY - Version 3.5.0

Copyright (C) 2001, 2010 NoMachine.
See http://www.nomachine.com/ for more information.

Info: Proxy running in client mode with pid '14480'.
Session: Starting session at 'Tue Oct  9 22:34:00 2018'.
Info: Connecting to remote host 'localhost:59245'.
Info: Connection to remote proxy 'localhost:59245' established.
Info: Connection with remote proxy completed.
Warning: Unrecognized session type 'unix-kde-depth_32'. Assuming agent session.
Warning: Failed to read data from the X auth command.
Warning: Generated a fake cookie for X authentication.
Info: Using ADSL link parameters 512/24/1/0.
Info: Using cache parameters 4/4096KB/8192KB/8192KB.
Info: Using pack method '16m-jpeg-9' with session 'unix-kde-depth_32'.
Info: Using ZLIB data compression 1/1/32.
Info: Using ZLIB stream compression 4/4.
Info: No suitable cache file found.
Info: Forwarding X11 connections to display 'localhost:0'.
Session: Session started at 'Tue Oct  9 22:34:00 2018'.Info: Using shared memory parameters 0/0K.
Info: Established X server connection.
Terminating session at 'Tue Oct  9 22:36:26 2018'.
Session: Session terminated at 'Tue Oct  9 22:36:26 2018'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the Solution and solution is

> Unity isn't supported under x2go. Use lxde, xfce or a plain, non-compositing WM like openbox. This is documented on the x2go project pages.

While i was trying with a option of GNOME